# How to pass file data from response into blob/downloadable document

Tags: javascript

How do I turn this response into a downloadable file URL? I have a tried a few ways with blob but the file it creates is unreadable. Where am I going wrong?

**My attempt:**

```
let blob = new Blob([data.data], {type: "octet/stream"});
    var url  = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.location.assign(url);
enter code here
```

**API Request to get the file data**

```
export const getDocumentByFileName = async (fileName: string) => {
    const client = await Client();
    const response = await client.get(`${endpoint}/Documents/Get?fileName=${fileName}`, {
        responseType: 'blob',
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.error('GET Document by fileName - ' + response.problem, response.data);
        return response;
    }

    // 204 No Content
    return response;
};
```

**Response data containing file:**

```
let data = {
    "duration": 92,
    "problem": null,
    "originalError": null,
    "ok": true,
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
        "date": "Thu, 04 Aug 2022 10:36:28 GMT",
        "server": "Kestrel"
    },
    "config": {
        "url": "Documents/Get?fileName=afbaa8fb-2669-4cf1-ad69-726a408934f6..docx",
        "method": "get",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "locale": "en-gb"
        },
        "params": {
            "responseType": "arraybuffer"
        },
        "baseURL": "/",
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        }
    },
    "data": "PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000!\u0000ߤ�lZ\u0001\u0000\u0000 \u0005\u0000\u0000\u0013\u0000\b\u0002[Content_Types].xml �\u0004\u0002(�\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\"
}
```

Comment: i think you need to return the arraybuffer to switch to blob

Comment: So response type blob instead of array buffer in my params? :)

Comment: which library are you using to send a request?

Comment: it can be handled easily by 1 line of code you shouldn't use buffer to complicate the problem

Comment: I have added my api request into the Q, one line really?!

Comment: `let blob = new Blob([data.data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"});`

Comment: to download it: `let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob); window.open(objectUrl);`

Comment: Thanks for getitng me on the right track everyone <3